# Hashtable with int array as key in java

Tags: java, hashtable, int

I'm trying to make a hashtable in java where the keys are int[], but it dosen't work. I have made a little test program to show my problem:

```
public class test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                int[] test0 = {1,1};
                int[] test1 = {1,1};
                Hashtable<int[], String> ht = new Hashtable<int[], String>();
                String s0 = "foo";

                ht.put(test0, s0);

                System.out.println("the result from ht.get(test1)");
                System.out.println(ht.get(test1));
                System.out.println("the result from ht.get(test0)");
                System.out.println(ht.get(test0));
        }
}
```

My intention is that both ht.get calles should return the same result, since the two arrays are equal, but they dont. Here is the result from running the code:

```
the result from ht.get(test1)
null
the result from ht.get(test0)
foo
```

Am I missing something here or is it just impossible to use int[] as keys in a hastable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use int[] as the key, but it has to be the same array, not just have the same content. (Which means it won't do what you want)

Arrays are not equals() or have the same hashCode() based on their content on if they are the same array.

The only way you can do this is to use a List<Integer> as a key or a wrapper for your int[] e.g. TIntArrayList.

try the following.

```
List<Integer> test0 = Arrays.asList(1,1);
List<Integer> test1 = Arrays.asList(1,1);
Map<List<Integer>, String> ht = new HashMap<List<Integer>, String>();
```

BTW: Hashtable is a legacy class IMHO, don't use it unless you have to.

Comment: Lists are (usually) mutable too.  The important difference is that [`List.equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`List.hashCode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29) are required to use element-wise equality.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's nice that i dont have to rethink all of my design:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create strings out of the arrays before hashing (unless the length of the array is prohibitively long) in addition to wrapping in a List

Should you choose the latter there is a static method of `Arrays` described here  [From java static Arrays class at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html))

```
h1.put(Arrays.toString(test1), s0);
```

Now you can hash this, and equivalent arrays will hash to the same thing.  You won't be able to recreate the array from the key, however (unless Java has some kind of `eval` now?)

.
.
.
.

For curiousities sake, here is me stupidly rolling my own until i found the above method:

```
public String intArrayToString(int[] x)
{
     String ans = '[';
     for(i = 0; i < size(x); i++)
         ans += '' + i + ',';
     return ans + ']';
}

HashTable<String,String> h1 = new HashTable<String,String> h1;
h1.put(intArrayToString(test1), s0);
```

If there is some kind of static toString that does this I apologize.
PS - does Java have reduce function (and lambdas), foreach loops, or eval (for reconstructing keys into array if need be) yet?  They would make this solution nicer...

Comment: Yes, there is the `Arrays.toString` static method. Apologies accepted, captain jon_darkstar.

Comment: turning the arrays into strings was also the solution that i had thought of my self, but i did not like the thought of the unnessesary overhead of creating the strings everytime i had to access something in the hashtable

Comment: well creating something like an ArrayList would do the same, but you could also just use them everywhere instead of arrays of primitives.  Of course you could wrap the `HashTable` put and get into new methods that create strings or ArrayList on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is array *test0* and *test1* have **different hashCodes**. If 2 keys have different hashcodes, they never can be same.